# What's wrong with this Groovy construct?

Tags: groovy

This is a short Groovy script:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
def dir = new File("/mydir")
def files = FileUtils.listFiles(dir, new String[] { "java" }, false)
```

It says:

```
No expression for the array constructor call at line: 2
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The call should be:

```
def files = FileUtils.listFiles(dir, [ "java" ] as String[], false)
```

Groovy uses Lists by default, and the `as` operator can be used to coerce these lists into arrays of a specified type (often for interacting with the java api as in this example)

**[edit]**

As an aside, you can do this with pure Groovy like so:

```
def files = dir.listFiles().findAll { it.name ==~ /.*\.java/ }
```

Then, you don't need Commons FileUtils

Comment: Thanks, Tim, I will follow your advice!