# Using TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] in Grails

Tags: groovy

How can i use the following code in grails --

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return;
                    }
                }
        };
```

The above code is working perfectly fine when i run the same code in a JAVA project but Grails is not compiling the code and giving error -- **No expression for the array constructor call** on the first line.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following piece of code will work:

```
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import java.security.cert.CertificateException

def trustAllCerts = [
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    }
] as TrustManager[]
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078238/whats-wrong-with-this-groovy-construct) question.

Comment: Thanks opal and i visited the same question you mentioned but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: @ChetanHallan if it works now, please accept the answer.